# Infinite Re-renders when using Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have started going through Hooks documentation and realized something.
When I use the function returned by useState() directly like:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
.
.
.
<button onClick={setCount(count + 1)}>+1</button>
```

React re-renders infinitely and gives maximum stacked reached error.
Why does this happen? Can anyone explain this to me in detail?

Comment: `onClick={setCount(count + 1)}` -> `onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}` One is a function call, the other is a function assignment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please add a anonymous function to your method object call.

```
<button onClick={setCount(count+1)} /> // will run every time.

<button onClick={() => setCount(count+1)} />  // will run once.
```

Comment: Why does the first one run every time?

Comment: Because the DOM is executing the function when rendered. Basically onClick works but at the same it's been. while using anon function will only execute when you execute this function.

Answer (score 1):

The first option runs every time because it executes on render and it always triggers a re-render creating an infinite loop. The second option is a function declaration and will only be executed once the `onClick` event is triggered.